# Heroku + ExpressJS + socket.io = Application Error

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, socket.io

I have a web app hosted in Heroku, doing some simple chat using socket.io.  However, when I deploy the codes to Heroku, i receive the following error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=project-interactive-wall.herokuapp.com request_id=e98ea8c9-2cc0-47e5-a9bb-4a0d863ac712 fwd="14.202.200.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

this is the code that I have in Heroku:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Any ideas?  Heroku documentation is not much help.

Comment: Could you share us the whole log?

Comment: @Gerardo

`2017-08-16T17:11:15.230475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-08-16T17:11:15.230475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-08-16T17:11:15.429796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-08-16T17:11:15.442189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: @Gerardo
`2017-08-16T21:44:27.601452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=project-interactive-wall.herokuapp.com request_id=f39a369e-9034-4285-8c41-aa2143677b76 fwd="14.202.200.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: `http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) { ... }` add that.

Comment: What heroku needs is `process.env.PORT` also a `start` script in `package.json`

Comment: it worked! thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku sets a `PORT` environment variable which is needed in your code to run the server.

Just add `process.env.PORT` to `http.listen()` to get it work.

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  // ...
})
```